Searching forwards from found class in xpath
I'm currently using full xpath to find an element in Java\Selenium.  The element has no id, so I only have div's and class to go on, here is my code.
driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/root/app-root/div/div[2]/resource-utilisation/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/utilisation-input/div/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div/ng-select")).getText()

Is there a way to find a class after another class you have found?
E.g., something like,
driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@class='resource-utilisation']//*[@class='utilisation-input']//*[@class='ng-select']"))


XPaths that start at /html or have that many levels are very brittle... they will break with the smallest changes to the page.  Please post a link to the page and indicate which element you are looking for so we can give you a better XPath.

Any chance you can change the html to add id's? This type of selector is very brittle. If the html changes slightly the test stops working

Yes, you can start searches from already found elements. A simple example would be.
WebElement e = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table"));
e.findElement(By.xpath("./tr"));
                        ^ note this period is required

NOTE: You must add a period to the start of the XPath of any chained .findElement() call.
